# Dog glitching problem in Scribblenauts Remix World 3 Level 10

Tags: scribblenauts-remix

In World 3 Level 10, I know I need a long bridge for the second area with the spikes, but every time I get past the first bridge (heavy bridge), the dog runs ahead to the end and goes back and forth so that I can't put the long bridge down.  Whenever I try, it just gets bumped and falls into the spikes.  Sometimes the super smart dog thinks that means it can cross the bridge and it jumps in after it!  Has anyone had this problem, or know how to fix it?

Comment: Can't you just make the dog ride a flying mini-cthulu? It worked in Unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

Make the bridges at the other end first then when it wants each bridge you type it in and put it somewhere else giving you the starite objectives.